# Mongoose update not working with embedded objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

I'm working in the MEAN stack, and I'm stuck on a Mongoose issue. Updates are working fine for individual documents(single key:value), but when I attempt to update a nested object with a new object, it's just deleting the original object and not inserting the new one.

Using an identical query directly in mongo, within the terminal, works perfectly. But from my Mongoose model, I get the above behavior.

My final desired query is more complicated and uses many variables, so I've simplified the code to the following to highlight the issue:

```
Setup.update({name: "main"}, {$set: {"schedule.sunday.eleven_pm": { associates: 111, supervisors: 111}}}, function(err){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            }
            else{
                console.log('successfully updated main schedule setup')
                Setup.find({}, function(err, setup){
                    if(err){
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                    else{
                        res.json(setup);
                    }
                })
            }
        });
```

Gives me this in my db:

```
"eleven_pm" : {

        }
```

But from terminal, the same query (cut and pasted from my mongoose query, just added 'db.setups' to beginning:

```
db.setups.update({name: "main"}, {$set: {"schedule.sunday.eleven_pm": { associates: 111, supervisors: 111}}})
```

Gives me this, the desired result:

```
    "eleven_pm" : {
            "associates" : 111,
            "supervisors" : 111
        }
```

I've tried writing this as a findOneAndUpdate(), but encountered the same behavior. Am I doing something unorthodox here?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: The `.update()` method returns "numAffected" as the response argument and not a document as you seem to be expecting. Use `.findOneAndUpdate()` instead, which returns the modifed document. Common mistake.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I don't think this solves my issue. I'm not expecting a document to be returned. The results I posted above are in the database, not returned documents. The mongoose update method is actually deleting(overwriting with blank) the document. Also, I mentioned in my post that I also tried the findOneAndUpdate() method, but encountered the same problematic behavior.

Comment: What you say here cannot be true. Please post the "Schema" to the model you are using to update. The problem here is most certainly there.

Comment: you're absolutely right, i had made a small change in my database structure that I neglected to back-edit to my Mongoose Schema for this collection. Now, it's working fine. Thank you for your help.

Comment: As this problem turned out to be strictly user error, my own, is it best etiquette for me to delete this question or leave it up? Thanks again

Comment: since it likely won't be of much help to anyone else, despite saving my day!

Answer (score 0):

A small change in my database structure was not amended in my Mongoose "Schema", and the difference between the two led to the unusual query behavior explained above.